# Python: How to test a RandomForest regression model for Overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, random-forest, overfitting

I'm a beginner in this area so maybe I'm doing something wrong here.
I'm using RandomForest for a regression model and wanted to see if my model is overfitting. Here is what I did:

EDIT:

I use GridSearchCV for hyperparameter tuning:

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0)
rf_params = {'n_estimators': [100, 500, 1000], 'max_depth': [3, 6, 9, None],
             'min_samples_leaf': [2, 5, 10], 'max_features':['auto', 'sqrt']}

gs_rf = GridSearchCV(rf, rf_params, scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error', cv = 10)

gs_rf.fit(x_train, y_train.values.ravel())
b = gs_rf.best_params_
```

Then I create a RandomForestRegressor with those parameters:

```
RF = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=b['n_estimators'], max_depth=b['max_depth'], min_samples_leaf=b['min_samples_leaf'], max_features=b['max_features'], random_state=0)
```

Then I fit the model using the train dataset:

```
model = RF.fit(x_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

Then I predict with the test dataset:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

Then I did the exact same with x_train instead of x_test:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_train)
```

Here are the results that I achieve:

```
Test Data:
MAE: 15.11
MAPE: 26.98%

Train Data:
MAE: 6.17
MAPE: 10.97%
```

As you can see there is a pretty significant difference.
Do I have a big problem with overfitting or am I doing something wrong when using x_train to predict?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Predicting on `x_train` and comparing the error with the prediction error of `x_test` is a good approach. Here, it *seems* that you are overfitting since you model is better to predict what it learned than new data. It would be a good thing to use a [cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) approach to ensure that the problem does not come from your split.

Here are some leads I would follow:

- Apply a cross-validation to evaluate your model
- If using cross-validation in hyperparameters tuning, it is important to keep a *validation* dataset to evaluate your final model after the tuning. Doing that, you ensure to test your model on unseen data.
- Have a look at your hyperparameters. You could for instance decrease `max_depth`, that may lead to reduce overfitting.
- Plot your outputs: plot the excepted values and the predicted ones. MAE is the *Mean Absolute Error*, so you may discover unexpected effects (such as your model having high troubles to predict specific range values and not others)

Hope it helps.

*Note*
I would not say overfitting *is* a problem, rather its consequences could be a problem. Overfitting occurs when the model learns too much from the training data and so does not generalize well. If you constructed your pipeline well, the metric that should lead your performance is the score you choose (in your case MAE)

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply! I used cross-validation in the GridSearchCV for the Hyperparameter Tuning. Is that what you mean? Or is there somewhere else I should use the cross-validation? max_depth was set to 'None' through the Hyperparameter Tuning, for which I used: 'max_depth': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, None]. Should I change something here? Once again, big thanks for helping out!

Comment: To follow up on this: I now tried it with setting max_depth=9. 
Now I get the following results: 
Test Data:
MAE: 16.01
MAPE: 28.19%
Train Data:
MAE: 13.11
MAPE: 20.54%

So while the overfitting problem seems to have gotten decreased, I also achieve slighty worse results with the Test Data. Is this desirable?

Comment: No it is not desirable. Overfitting is one problem, but sure the goal is to build a model that performs well-enough according to our needs. I also added a bullet point to use a third dataset to evaluate the final model after hyperparameters tuning

Comment: thanks, wouldn't the test dataset be an unseen dataset? or am I mistaken here? could you maybe provide a link on how using a third dataset would work?

Comment: Sure, you could read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-validation-and-test-sets-72cb40cba9e7). Notice that I mixed validation and test dataset... However, in your case, because you did the hyperparameters tuning using all the data, you don't have this unseen test dataset, if I understand correctly how you proceed.

Comment: I used only the train data for the hyperparameters tuning. I updated my original post by including the GridSearchCV part of the HP tuning, maybe you can have a look and let me know if there is a mistake there.

Comment: The thing I don't understand about HP Tuning is that, since it is trained on the training set, isn't it obvious that it would lead to overfitting since it is only optimized for that data? Even though HP Tuning using cv should actually reduce the overfitting?

Comment: Ok, my mistake, so you have an unseen test dataset :). After a quick look, I don't see any mistake in your grid search.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117299/discussion-between-etiennedm-and-0009).

Comment: Any chance you could check the chat again? Would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: hey etienne if you have any time to take a look at our chat again, that would be really nice! :)